# 'toggel' rotation of element back and forth using css3/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

i've got an image that i want to onclick animate the rotation 90degress, when its clicked again i want it to animate the rotation -90degrees.

For the rotation im using the css3 transform:

```
-moz-transform:rotate(90deg); 
-webkit-transform:rotate(90deg); 
-ms-transform:rotate(90deg);
```

For the jquery I want to set a varable to check if the object has been rotated, then act accordingly.

I have been having a real difficult time trying to get it to work. I've put together a [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/58Nfn/).

This is the code I am using:

```
var turn = true;
$("#button").click(function () {
    $("#shape").css('transform', function(index) {
      return index * 90;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add some transitions and a rotate class, and just toggle that class:

css:

```
#shape  { width: 100px; 
          height: 200px; 
          background:#000;
          -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
          -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
          -o-transition: all 1s ease;
           transition: all 1s ease;
         }

.rotate {-moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
         -webkit-transform:rotate(90deg); 
         -ms-transform:rotate(90deg);
         -o-transform:rotate(90deg);
         }
```

js:

```
$("#button").click(function() {
    $("#shape").toggleClass('rotate');
});​
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/58Nfn/9/)

Answer (score 2):

If I understood correct, [THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/58Nfn/2/) should do it.

Comment: +1 great job. I couldnt get the animation to work and I didn't think of doing it the way you did it

Answer (score 0):

I think in general, if you're going to use transition's you should target the specific properties you want to affect. I would consider the use of "all" to be poor practice.

Target alternative:
css:

```
#shape  { 
    width: 100px; 
    height: 200px; 
    background:#000;
    -moz-transition: transform 1s ease;
    -webkit-transition: transform 1s ease;
    -o-transition: transform 1s ease;
    transition: transform 1s ease;
}

.rotate {
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(90deg); 
    -ms-transform:rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(90deg);
    transform:rotate(90deg);
}

///jquery

$("#button").click(function() {
    $("#shape").toggleClass('rotate');
});​
```